# Problem with nVidia GPU, not working lightdm

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, lightdm

I'm trying all day to get my nVidia GT650M working, but without success. I tried to switch graphics card in nVidia Prime, but after logout screen goes black and Light Display Manager won't start, computer works only in terminal mode. Tried switching drivers (352, 340 and 304), didn't work. I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 LTS.

**EDIT:** in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit used:

```
sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1 bumblebee* nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime prime-indicator
```

Works wonders. Samsung 550-P5C, GT650M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tried all drivers from the Ubuntu repositories without success,
 install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers 358 from the GPU Drivers PPA.

First remove the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers for GT 650M.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

In case it still does not work ... perform the installation in a different way :
Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute the commands.

**Update addressing your feedback that you can't see the GRUB boot menu**

Boot from Ubuntu installation media and select Try Ubuntu without installing.
When the Ubuntu desktop appears ... open a terminal and mount the system :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

Replace **XY** with the partition number (**e.g. sda1**) to which Ubuntu is installed.
To identify the partition open GParted - it is included in the installation media.

```
sudo gedit /mnt/etc/default/grub
```

Add **#** in front of the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 line, so that it reads exactly :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Save the changes and reboot the PC ... now you will see the GRUB boot menu !

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After executing these commands and second reboot, no desktop manager started and once again I was in terminal mode. I don't have GRUB boot menu, where should I put nouveau.modeset=0?

Comment: @Szczepan : When you boot the computer, there is no boot menu ? Does Ubuntu directly start when you switch on the PC ? - Is Ubuntu the only OS you have installed ?

Comment: Yes, it is only OS.

Answer (score 0):

@cl-netbox, thanks for effort. Your reply helped a lot.
I did your first commands and added just one thing:

```
sudo tee /sys/module/rcutree/parameters/rcu_idle_gp_delay <<<1
```

Now everything works perfect :)